# how to run a mysql process in docker file with node.js child process

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, child-process

I'm aiming to retrieve MySQL output using a child process in Node.js. Below is a Dockerfile that defines the MySQL container, a sample SQL script (backup.sql), and a set of shell commands to accomplish the task.

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Use the official MySQL image as the base image
FROM mysql:latest

WORKDIR /app
# Set environment variables for MySQL
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database
ENV MYSQL_USER=my_user
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=my_password

# Expose the MySQL port
EXPOSE 3306
```

**backup.sql:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fruits`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
  `fruit_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fruit_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

LOCK TABLES `fruits` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `fruits` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `fruits` VALUES ('apple','red',20),('banana','yellow',30);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `fruits` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

SELECT * FROM fruits;
```

To obtain MySQL results using shell commands:

1. Start the MySQL container:

```
docker run -d --name run_mysql -v <volume_path>:/app my-mysql-image:latest
```

2. Access the container's bash:

```
docker exec -it run_mysql /bin/bash
```

3. Execute MySQL commands:

```
mysql -u root -proot_password my_database < backup.sql
```

I can get the result of command above:

```
fruit_name  color   price
apple   red 20
banana  yellow  30
```

How to achieve the same result with node.js child process like exec?

Comment: You should be able to use an ordinary MySQL client library to connect to the database.  Run the application in a _separate_ container – do not try to run the two things in the same container or one as a subprocess of another.  You do not need `docker exec` or similar debugging commands to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run -d --name run_mysql -p 3306:3306 -v <volume_path>:/app my-mysql-image:latest
```

You missed to open the port so the child process in nodejs is not able to connect.